# on first click sort by asc and on second by desc asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting

I'm trying to make my view sortable by table's  menu items.

here's my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = "name";
            ViewBag.descSortParm = "description";
            ViewBag.beginDateSortParm = "beginDate";
            ViewBag.endDateSortParm = "endDate";
            ViewBag.priceSortParm ="price";


            var persons = from s in db.PRT_FEE_PRICES
                          select s;
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.NAME);
                    break;
                case "description":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.DESCRIPTION);
                    break;
                case "beginDate":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.BEGIN_DATE);
                    break;
                case "endDate":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.END_DATE);
                    break;
                case "price":
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.PRICE);
                    break;
                default:
                    persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.NAME);
                    break;
            }

            return View(persons.ToList());
        }
```

and here's view

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("სახელი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("აღწერა", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.descSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("დაწყების თარიღ", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.beginDateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("დამთავრების თარიღი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.endDateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("ფასი", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.priceSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIPTION)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BEGIN_DATE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.END_DATE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRICE)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

it works perfect sorts everything. How can I do that on second click it sorts these fields by descending? I have no idea how to do that?

Comment: Instead of redirecting each time, use ajax to update the table. Not only will it give better performance, you can then have javascript variables to hold a value(s) for the sort order that can be toggled on each call (pass values for the sort order (asc or desc) and the sort name to the method. Better still you can do this all on the client side using javascript without having to call a server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to commute the value received on the Controller method to switch between ascending or descending order.

In example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "name" ? "name_desc" : "name";
    // Rest of your sortOrder param goes here...

    var persons = from s in db.PRT_FEE_PRICES
                  select s;
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name":
            persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.NAME);
            break;
        case "name_desc":
            persons = persons.OrderByDescending(s => s.NAME);
            break;
        // ...
    }

    return View(persons.ToList());
}
```

My answer is based on the example of the Get Started tutorial on this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 0):

You can using if..else loop in switch loop and change your name list and sorting your data.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "name" ? "name_desc" : "name";
    // Rest of your sortOrder param goes here...

    var persons = from s in db.PRT_FEE_PRICES
                  select s;
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name":
            if(sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
        persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.NAME);
           else
         persons = persons.OrderByDescending(s => s.NAME);
            break;
        `enter code here` // ...
    }

    return View(persons.ToList());
}
```

and your View is Here.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("სახელი", "Index", new { sortOrder = "name",  CurrentSort = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
............
//enter your remaining code...//
.....
```